# How to limit a built-in admin permission in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an user account which is in administrator group on the machine say the name is "admin.x".

As a result, it's also on the `BUILTIN\Administrators` list in SQL Server hosted on the server which means "admin.x" also has the db admin permission.

I tried to grant it only `db_datareader` (Security -> Logins -> right click "admin.x" -> properties -> User Mapping -> select target database -> check public and db_datareader). With this configuration I thought, it could only read data, definitely without writing. However, it's still able to write, update and delete, which seems builtin administrator is still working.

The problem is "admin.x" still needs to be the machine admin but only has data read permission in database.

Comment: To be clear, do you or do you now have control of the window accounts?  is this your sql server or is it hosted by third party?

Comment: @MisterPositive Yeah, I have the control. "admin.x" is the account we provide for our automation tool. It needs to be admin on the machine so that it could fulfill certain jobs (e.g. start, stop IIS, etc.) but it should only have read permission on the database. It's hosted on one of servers that we have full control.

Comment: Is the user a member of the sysadmins group?

Comment: @MisterPositive no, "admin.x" is not in sysadmins group. But it's admin of the server so it goes into builtin\administrators automatically.

Comment: by design: [KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/932881) covers 2005, but is reported to be the same for 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a new admin group for sql server, add the appropriate members to it, grant the group sysadmin rights, and then remove the builtin\Administrators group.

Then you can grant your admin.x user specific datareader rights.

Comment: Hi actually I discussed with my team and we decided to remove "admin.x" from administrator group and only grant it db_reader on the specified table. However, the fun thing is it still able to update and delete the table

Comment: I ran this sql: SELECT SUSER_NAME(), user_name(); it returned "admin.x" and dbo, so I think I must miss something ... shouldn't be dbo